# How to set default selected dropdown with different values from same source

Tags: angularjs

I have an JSON array from where i am creating Dropdown and default selected using `ng-model`

```
$scope.repeats = [{
    'title': 'Never',
    'value': 'Never'
  }, {
    'title': 'Daily',
    'value': 'Daily'
  }, {
    'title': 'Weekdays (M-F)',
    'value': 'Weekdays'
  }, {
    'title': 'Weekly',
    'value': 'Weekly'
  }, {
    'title': 'Monthly',
    'value': 'Monthly'
  }, {
    'title': 'Yearly',
    'value': 'Yearly'
  }, {
    'title': 'Hourly',
    'value': 'Hourly'
  }, {
    'title': 'Minutely',
    'value': 'Minutely'
  }];

$scope.def_sele = $scope.repeats[0]
```

In the view:

```
<select ng-model="def_sele" ng-options="repeat.title for repeat in repeats"></select>
```

From the above code the default selected dropdown is `Daily`. Till here it was all fine.

But i am creating an TODO application where each TODO has different selection(`Never, Daily` etc.. from above `$scope.repeats`)

So, how to set default selected for each TODO ????? Because the above example i've given it applies every where and i get `Daily` selected on each TODO, but i want to select different different for each TODO, how to do that????

---

**Updated**

My code is like:

```
<ul ng-repeat="todo in todos_detail">
    <select ng-model="todo.dropdown_position_index" ng-options="repeat.title for repeat in repeats"></select>
</ul>
```

In the above example for each `todo` has a different `dropdown_position_index`, so i want the dropdown is `selected = selected` using `todo.dropdown_position_index`.

Comment: Please show the ToDos and how you are handling them.

Comment: pass a different model to each select and if you need them all to get synced upon a selection sue the ng-change method to alter the rest

Comment: @Dayan is it possible to give me an example to sue the ng change method to alter the rest?

Comment: I have extended the @nilsK answer to update the other todos. in this link
http://plnkr.co/edit/UI7Vkp4u5cxvGUVXLKfs?p=preview

Comment: @DayanMorenoLeon i've tried your code but i want the output in another way,i've updated my question how my code looks like, please check updated question in the end....and also let me know if you don'e understand..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure the value you're selecting in your `<select>` lines up with the value in your selected `todo`.

I haven't seen your code, so [I put together a working example in jsbin](http://jsbin.com/kepijide/2/edit?html,js,output).

The basic idea is this:

```
<select ng-model="X" ng-options="x.A as x.B for x in Z"></select>
```

Where:

- Z = your collection of options
- x = an individual item variable from Z
- x.A = the *value* of the option
- x.B = the *text* of the option
- X = the value to update *AND* read from

as long as the array `Z` has an object in it `x` where the property `x.A` is equal to `X`, it will be selected.

... or for a less confusing answer, [check the code example](http://jsbin.com/kepijide/2/edit?html,js,output). ;)

Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

given for the example object structure

```
$scope.todos = [{
   'title': 'Weekly',
   'value': 'Weekly'
}, {
  'title': 'Yearly',
  'value': 'Yearly'
}];
```

you could do something like this

```
<div ng-repeat="todo in todos">
  <select ng-model="todo.value" ng-options="repeat.value as repeat.title for repeat in repeats"></select>
</div>
```

[here an example plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Oabq1bEbQy6fo63sLmY5?p=preview)

Comment: i've tried your code but i want the output in another way,i've updated my question how my code looks like, please check updated question in the end....and also let me know if you don'e understand..